# Expecting a string but getting an array

Tags: javascript, sendgrid

I want to get an array which has objects that contains string, but I am only getting the array without objects or string

```
const emails = [
  {
    email: "dot@gmail.com",
  },
  {
    email: "ke@gmail.com",
  },
];

const msg = {

  personalizations: emails.map((email) => ({
    to: [{ email: email.email }],
    subject: "Hello World from the Personalization API!",
  })),

};
```

when i console log msg I get:

```
{
  personalizations: [
    {
      to: [Array],
      subject: 'Hello World from the Personalization API!'
    },
    {
      to: [Array],
      subject: 'Hello World from the Personalization API!'
    }
  ],
}
```

I want get the values of to when I console log like this:

```
  "personalizations": [
    {
      "to": [
        {
          "email": "john@example.com"
        }
      ],
      "send_at": 1600188812
    },
    {
      "to": [
        {
          "email": "jane@example.com"
        }
      ],
      "send_at": 1600275471
    }
  ]
```

Comment: The output in the console log is expected. You just loop through it and do whatever you want to do.

Comment: Don't expect the console to give you a complete view of values; it tries to abbreviate things to help in debugging. The arrays in your output are in fact the arrays you expect.  You might try `console.dir(msg)` instead of `console.log(msg)`.

Comment: Or try `console.log(msg.personalizations[0].to)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As from the output. It's very easy to do. I believe all you need is `JSON.stringify()`
So:  `console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));`,  It should do the job.
Though, for making it readable, you need [JSON Prettier](https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print)

Comment: But then the OP will have a string and not an array at all.

Comment: I think the OP only wants to see the output `I want get the values of to when I console log like this:`   
it doesn't show that because it's an output from a library, hence to make all visible, `JSON.stringify` is an easy option

Comment: Wait: what you mean is `console.log(JSON.stringify(msg))`, right? If so, yes that's a fine idea.

Comment: Well... to be honest, I thought everyone would understand it already without even mentioning, but yeah, could be clearer, updated, cheers.

Comment: Well people recommend weird stuff like using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xyz))` a lot,  which often works, sort-of, but it's usually not the best idea. Thus I at least wasn't sure what you meant, but as I said it makes perfect sense now that I get it.